# How to rename columns starting with 20 dynamically Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, rename

I have columns in my dataframe like this where the columns starting with 20 were generated dynamically.

[image]

I want to rename the columns starting with 20 to 2019_p, 2020_p, 2021_p dynamically.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.select(*[col(c).alias(f"${c}_p") if c.startswith("20") else col(c) for c in df.columns])
```

Comment: Hi @Robert Kossendey, thanks for the answer.  I have 2 data frames with same columns one ending without _p and one ending with _p.  I want to final select the columns whether without _p or with _p based on a condition using when statement. How do I achieve this?

Comment: This is a different question @sparc, maybe you can create a new one, this helps people that have the same question as you.

Comment: Hi @Robert Kossendey, I have raised another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269611/select-columns-based-on-a-condition-pyspark
Please can you answer. Thank you.