# Select columns based on a condition Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have columns in my dataframe df1 like this where the columns starting with 20 were generated dynamically.

[image]

I could rename the columns starting with 20 to 2019_p, 2020_p, 2021_p dynamically using

```
df.select(*[col(c).alias(f"${c}_p") if c.startswith("20") else col(c) for c in df.columns])
```

[image]

Now I have 2 dataframes one with original dataframe and another data frame with columns starting with 20 and ending with _p.  I want to final select the columns based on whichever is not null either without _p or with_p.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: it depends on the condition -- please share more (rather all) details on the conditions and your approach

Comment: Hi @samkart, I have edited my question, I would like to select the columns based on whichever is not null either without _p or with _p. How do I achieve that?

Comment: share input sample and expected output along with explanation on how you achieve the expected output. please see [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `when` and `otherwise` combination. Assuming the condition is that if `without _p` is not null, then choose `without _p`, otherwise choose `with _p`:

```
df.select(*[func.when(func.col(f"{col}_p").isNotNull(), func.col(f"{col}_p")).otherwise(func.col(f"{col}")).alias(f"select_{col}") for col in df.columns])
```

---

Edit 1:
I have test the code and it should work. Can you just try one or two column first?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, None, 1, None),
        (None, 2, None, 2)
    ],
    schema=['a', 'a_p', 'b', 'b_p']
)

df.show(10, False)
+----+----+----+----+
|a   |a_p |b   |b_p |
+----+----+----+----+
|1   |null|1   |null|
|null|2   |null|2   |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Using the same logic:

```
df.select(*[func.when(func.col(f"{col}_p").isNotNull(), func.col(f"{col}_p")).otherwise(func.col(f"{col}")).alias(f"select_{col}") for col in ['a', 'b']]).show(10, False)
+--------+--------+
|select_a|select_b|
+--------+--------+
|1       |1       |
|2       |2       |
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Lam, I have used your code but I am getting 'str' object is not callable error. Any idea why

Comment: Hi @sparc, I have updated the answer, you can check if it helps.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Lam, I also want to select columns Id and Type. How can I select those columns too?

Comment: Hi @sparc, you can just add the id and type in the select statement, just like `df.select('id', 'type', *[...])`

Answer (score 0):

You can just alter the condition of the rename like this:

```
df.select(*[col(c).alias(f"${c}_p") if c.startswith("20") and NEW CONDITION else col(c) for c in df.columns])
```

with NEW CONDITION being a condition that, if true, selects the column with the _p name.

Comment: Hi @Robert Kossendey, I want to select the final columns without _p or with _p whichever is not null. How do I achieve this?