# Dynamically select the columns in a Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, dynamic, apache-spark-sql, multiple-columns

I have data like in the dataframe below. As you can see, there are columns "2019" and "2019_p", "2020" and "2020_p", "2021" and "2021_p".

[image]

I want to select the final columns dynamically where if "2019" is null, take the value of "2019_p" and if the value of "2020" is null, take the value of "2020_p" and the same applies to "2021" etc.

I want to select the columns dynamically without hardcoding the column names.
How do I achieve this?

I need output like this:

[image]

Comment: from a duplicate question, this is a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74271378/1290485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simplify ZygD's approach to just use a list comprehension with `coalesce` (without regex).

```py
# following list can be created from a source dataframe as well
year_cols = ['2019', '2020', '2021']
# [k for k in data_sdf.columns if k.startswith('20') and not k.endswith('_p')]

data_sdf. \
    select('id', 'type',
           *[func.coalesce(c, c+'_p').alias(c) for c in year_cols]
           ). \
    show()

# +---+----+----+----+----+
# | id|type|2019|2020|2021|
# +---+----+----+----+----+
# |  1|   A|  50|  65|  40|
# |  1|   B|  25|  75|  75|
# +---+----+----+----+----+
```

where the list comprehension would yield the following

```py
[func.coalesce(c, c+'_p').alias(c) for c in year_cols]

# [Column<'coalesce(2019, 2019_p) AS `2019`'>,
#  Column<'coalesce(2020, 2020_p) AS `2020`'>,
#  Column<'coalesce(2021, 2021_p) AS `2021`'>]
```

Answer (score 1):

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'A', 50, None, 40, None, 65, None),
     (1, 'B', None, 75, None, 25, None, 75)],
    ['Id', 'Type', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2019_p', '2020_p', '2021_p'])
```

One way could be this - using `df.colRegex`:

```py
cols = list({c[:4] for c in df.columns if c not in ['Id', 'Type']})
df = df.select(
    'Id', 'Type',
    *[F.coalesce(*df.select(df.colRegex(f'`^{c}.*`')).columns).alias(c) for c in cols]
)

df.show()
# +---+----+----+----+----+
# | Id|Type|2020|2019|2021|
# +---+----+----+----+----+
# |  1|   A|  65|  50|  40|
# |  1|   B|  75|  25|  75|
# +---+----+----+----+----+
```

Also possible using `startswith`:

```py
cols = list({c[:4] for c in df.columns if c not in ['Id', 'Type']})
df = df.select(
    'Id', 'Type',
    *[F.coalesce(*[x for x in df.columns if x.startswith(c)]).alias(c) for c in cols]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you needed a one liner, create a dictionary of the columns and use k, value pair in the coalesce

```
df.select( 'Id','Type',*[coalesce(k,v).alias(k) for k,v in dict(zip(df.select(df.colRegex("`\\d{4}`")).columns,df.select(df.colRegex("`.*\\_\\D$`")).columns)).items()]).show()

+---+----+----+----+----+
| Id|Type|2019|2020|2021|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|   A|  50|  65|  40|
|  1|   B|  25|  75|  75|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```